# how can i move properly drag and move a line around in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

i can successfully move a line around the window in wpf but it's not working properly.
it's like if the cursor is way fast that the line it's dragging.
you can test the code to see if you can find what's the problem on it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Line line = new Line();
    Point p ; 
    bool isdragging = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        canvas1.Children.Add(line);
        Thickness thickness = new Thickness(101, -11, 362, 250);
        line.Margin = thickness;
        line.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        line.StrokeThickness = 4;
        line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        line.X1 = 10;
        line.X2 = 200;
        line.Y1 = 0;
        line.Y2 = 70;
        line.MouseDown+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(line_MouseDown);
        line.MouseMove+=new MouseEventHandler(line_MouseMove);
        line.MouseUp+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(line_MouseUp);

    }

    public void line_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isdragging = true;
        p = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
    }
    public void line_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isdragging == true && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            line.X1 += e.GetPosition(canvas1).X - p.X;
            line.X2 += e.GetPosition(canvas1).X - p.X;
            line.Y1 += e.GetPosition(canvas1).Y - p.Y;
            line.Y2 += e.GetPosition(canvas1).Y - p.Y;

        }
    }
    public void line_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isdragging = false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want really smooth dragging you could wrap the `Line` in a `Thumb` so you can use the `DragDelta` event to calculate the new position.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="233" Width="405" Name="UI">
    <Canvas>
        <Thumb DragDelta="onDragDelta" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" >
            <Thumb.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Line X1="10" X2="200" Y1="0" Y2="70" StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="Black"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void onDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        var thumb = sender as Thumb;
        Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the line after *every* mouse move event. This will cause the code to attempt to redraw the line in it's new location after every slightest move of the mouse - even down to a single pixel.

You could keep a track of the position and only redraw the line if the mouse has moved more than a certain amount:

```
public void line_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isdragging == true && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Point newPos = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
        if (Size(p, newPos) > 10)
        {
            line.X1 += newPos.X - p.X;
            line.X2 += newPos.X - p.X;
            line.Y1 += newPos.Y - p.Y;
            line.Y2 += newPos.Y - p.Y;
            p = newPos;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `Size` is a method that calculates the distance from `p` to `newPos`.

Then you just need to add a final update when the mouse is released so that the line ends up where the user expects it to be:

```
public void line_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point newPos = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
    line.X1 += newPos.X - p.X;
    line.X2 += newPos.X - p.X;
    line.Y1 += newPos.Y - p.Y;
    line.Y2 += newPos.Y - p.Y;
    isdragging = false;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick and interesting response. your solution is working fine if i am moving the cursor real slow around the window, but if i'm moving it fast (even not fast) i get the same result as with the first code.

Comment: @user2019747 - it looks like the drawing code can't keep up with the amount of redraw events you are generating. Are you seeing this with only one line being drawn?

Comment: @user2019747 - the Thickness you've set up seems rather odd - especially that -11.

Comment: you can try with whatever thickness you like, the result is about the same as in the very first code.

Comment: @user2019747 - ah yes. That would work. Post that as an answer so you can a) mark the problem as solved by accepting an answer and b) possibly earn some rep from it. You may have to wait a bit before you're allowed to answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for you help!!
i think i solved that problem buy capturing the mouse when i'm m and i release the mouse capture after releasing the button of the mouse.
it works just fine. 
thank you again guys!